# How can we start a simple project with Raspberry Pi 3 Model with android things using Chirp?

Tags: android-things, chirp

I Have an app which generates the pickup code for my vending Machine and I used to enter that pickup code on the tab which is attached to the vending machine, after enter the pickup code, it dispense my order. And for all that, needs proper internet every time. I want to try it by chirp protocol.
Can any one suggest how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Chirp.io provides a series of [SDK's](https://developers.chirp.io/docs/using-chirp/platforms) for different platforms including Android. Taking in consideration that Android Things is based on Android, the Chirp Android SDK should just work but we didn't tested it yet on a real device.

Check out [developers documentation](https://developers.chirp.io/docs) for more info about how to use ChirpSDK's and for a quick test you can install one of the demo apps provided with the SDK zip package you can get from [downloads page](https://developers.chirp.io/downloads).

Comment: How can we start a simple project with Raspberry Pi 3 Model with android things using Chirp?

Comment: Check out [chirp-android-examples](https://github.com/chirp/chirp-android-examples) repository which should be a good starting point for implementing the ChirpSDK.  Regarding Android Things, I guess [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/things/) is the best source.

Comment: I am not able to integrate Chirp SDK with Android things. Can anyone help in this?

Comment: Does anyone know about it?